# bash script to recursively run commands on directories depending on the pattern of the directory name

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a small bash script to help sort some recovered directories/files back to their original file structure prior to the recovery.  In a nutshell I have recovered a pool of disks that were pooled using aufs union file system, after the recovery of deleted directories/files I noticed that in a lot of the directories there are directories named ".wh..wh.original_dir_name.4_random_characters" for example ".wh..wh.Images.1E7W".  This directory would be located in the same directory where the actual "Images" directory is located.  These .wh directories are referred to as white space and are created by the aufs file system usually during delete operations but I noticed there are a lot of recoverable files/directories located in these but I would like to integrate them back into the normal structure.

To paraphrase, this is what I want to do but do not know how to piece it together in a bash script.

I need recursively traverse the structure, when I find a directory named something like .wh..wh. then I need to parse the real name of the directory and if this directory already exists in the same directory then execute `cp -r --backup=numbered .wh..wh./* real_directory_name/` and then delete the .wh..wh directory or if the directory does not exist then simply rename the directory using the `mv` command. I assume that I would use the `find` command to traverse the structure but again not sure how to piece it altogether.  Any help would be awesome.

Here is an example file structure to clarify things:

```
    /home/
    /home/.wh..wh.Images.67TY/
    /home/.wh..wh.Images.67TY/Camping/
    /home/Images/
    /home/Images/Camping/
```

In the above example I would like to use the `cp` command to copy the contents of /home/.wh..wh.Images.67TY to /home/Images and then delete /home/.wh..wh.Images.67TY

Comment: How do you know it's `Images` and not `Images.67TY`? I suppose you just know it, but is there any rule, like "my real directory names don't have a "." in it or "the wh-directories always end in an additional 4-letter suffix"?

Comment: put it this way....strip off the proceeding '.wh..wh.' and the trailing characters after the last '.' (period) and it will always leave the true directory name regardless if it was called for example 'Images.test', which would be something like '.wh..wh.Images.test.67TY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using only bash parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

for BACKUPDIR in $(find . -type d -name ".wh..wh.*")
do
    BASE=$(dirname "${BACKUPDIR}")

    LASTPART=$(basename "${BACKUPDIR}")
    D1=${LASTPART#.wh..wh.}
    D2=${D1%.*}

    if [ -d "${BASE}/${D2}" ]
    then
         cp -a "${BACKUPDIR}/"* "${BASE}/${D2}"
    else
         mv "${FILEPATH}" "${BASE}/${D2}"
    fi

done
```

Haven't tested the copy/move part; you should first see with echo, if this gives you, what you want.

Comment: I follow the above code, but have one question regarding the `D2=${D1%.*}`.  Will this handle a case where the real directory is named something like "Images.test"?  I looked into parameter expansion but did not readily find anything that would confirm that for me.

Comment: Never mind, just found a good tutorial on parameter expansion....from what I can tell it will handle that situation.  Will test this later when I get home and will update then.  Thanks

Comment: slight change to the script got the job done!  Below is the modified script I used for reference....

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# handles directory names with spaces
IFS='
'
for BACKUPDIR in $(find . -depth -type d -name ".wh..wh.*")
do
    BASE=$(dirname "${BACKUPDIR}")
    LASTPART=$(basename "${BACKUPDIR}")
    D1=${LASTPART#.wh..wh.}
    D2=${D1%.*}

    if [ -d "${BASE}/${D2}" ]
    then
       echo copying from "${BACKUPDIR}" to "${BASE}/${D2}"
       # prevents deleting if the cp command fails
       if cp -a --backup=numbered "${BACKUPDIR}/"* "${BASE}/${D2}"
       then
           echo deleting "${BACKUPDIR}"
           rm -rf "${BACKUPDIR}"
       fi
    else
        echo moving "${BACKUPDIR}" to "${BASE}/${D2}"
        mv "${BACKUPDIR}" "${BASE}/${D2}"
    fi
done
```